# How to implement map method on variable containing json object with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to apply a money formatter in a variable because it is only accessible to be formatted after I have already push the array. Is it possible for me to format a variable containing several json objects using map? for example:

```
            for (var j = 0; j < totalOfPurchased.length; j++) {
                // Declare Variables Containing Extend Details
                var purchasedProductNested = totalOfPurchased[j].purchasedProduct;
                var quantityOfPurchasedNested = totalOfPurchased[j].quantityPurchased;
                var totalOfPurchasedNested = totalOfPurchased[j].totalOfPurchased;
                var totalOfDiscountsPurchasedNested = totalOfPurchased[j].discountsToConsider;

                // Here's The Point I'm Having Trouble
                totalOfPurchasedNested = totalOfPurchasedNested.map(v => v.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", "."));

                // Final JSON Array Containing Extend Details
                var allResponseTwoWithExtendDetails = {
                    product: purchasedProductNested,
                    quantity: quantityOfPurchasedNested,
                    totalPurchased: totalOfPurchasedNested,
                    totalDiscounts: totalOfDiscountsPurchasedNested
                };

                // Push Group With Received JSON In Native Array
                receivedDataOne.push(allResponseTwoWithExtendDetails);
            }
```

[- Live project in JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/smachs/o283ufvm/)

When I try to apply a map to a variable an error is printed saying that `totalOfPurchasedNested` it is not a function :C

```
totalOfPurchasedNested = totalOfPurchasedNested.map(v => v.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", "."));
```

I intend to use this array formatted in a grouping and accounting linQ function of best products sell, example:

```
{product: "botijão 13KG", quantity: "10", totalPurchased: "220,00", totalDiscounts: "200,00"}
{product: "botijão 13KG", quantity: "4", totalPurchased: "208,00", totalDiscounts: "0,00"}
{product: "botijão 13KG", quantity: "13", totalPurchased: "666,00", totalDiscounts: "10,00"}
```

I'm going to clean up this final `array`, but this is what I want to be able to use in my `map` function in variables containing `json` so that I can format the money that is being stored and thanks for the help :D

```
{product: "botijão 13KG", quantity: 9, totalOfPurchasedNested: 26901.97},
{product: "botijão 25KG", quantity: 4, totalOfPurchasedNested: 4000.96}
```

Comment: when debugging you can see that you call `.map` of string `"220,00"`, because your `totalPurchased` is string. `map` is available on arrays.

Comment: You should use `reduce` instead of `map` because with reduce you can `map` and `filter` in one function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly you no longer need `map` since you're already running a loop through each object in the array.

Your code here is already there: `totalOfPurchasedNested = totalOfPurchasedNested.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", "."));`

I forked your fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/vzy29zju/

Comment: it's easier than I thought I thought I could not perform this action without a function, thx m8 :D

Answer (score 1):

1- `.map` does not modify the array data if you want you can use `.forEach`

2- `totalOfDiscountsPurchasedNested` is not an array rather it's a string so you better use

```
 totalOfPurchasedNested = totalOfPurchasedNested.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", ".");
```

See the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o283ufvm/1/)

Comment: `map` does not modify the array data? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Array#map creates a new array of the created items and returns that. You need to return each item from the function. After you need to assign the returned result.

Comment: Yes Joseph I did, not need to start another function since I am already looping through each object in the array any way thanks for the suggestion